# Adafruit rotary encoder I2C Board

Tags: circuit-analysis

I have an Adafruit rotary encoder I2C board without the rotary encoder "button". Can I use EC11 rotary encoder instead?

[image: Photo of top side of Adafruit rotary encoder I2C board]

[image: Photo of EC11 rotary encoder]

[image: Dimensions of EC11 rotary encoder]

[image: Features of EC11 rotary encoder]

Comment: Please provide data sheet links for both PCB and switch/button.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *instead*... instead of what? Do you mean "Can I use the EC11 with the Adafruit rotary encoder i2c board?"?

Comment: Yes . That's exactly what am asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The info page for the [Adafruit rotary encoder I2C board](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-i2c-qt-rotary-encoder?view=all) states:

> This breakout does not come with an encoder soldered on, so you can pick whatever encoder you like. [We sell a common 24-detent-with-switch encoder here and it works wonderfully](https://www.adafruit.com/product/377).

If you follow this link, it links to [Rotary Encoder + Extras](https://www.adafruit.com/product/377), which (at the bottom of the page) links to the spec sheet, [PEC11-4215F-S24 datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/pec11.pdf), which (given the first part of the data sheet name) would *seem* to be the EC11 that you wish to use - if I've understood your question correctly.

So, yes, is the answer.

Comment: In general, rotary encoders are all very similar.  As long as the chosen encoder is the same size and pinout order (most are), it should work.

Comment: *Cheap mechanical hobbyist* rotary encoders are all very similar.

Comment: The data sheet located at Adafruit website is for thier rotary encoder which is called PEC11

Comment: My question is can i substitute PEC11 button , the one that adafruit sells with CE11 rotary encoder shown in my attachments above